# R Project structure and variable scope

Tags: r

this might apply to other languages and not be limited to R but I came across this while trying to build an R project so I am posting here.

Let's say in my project I have

```
- Main.R
- Utilities.R
```

and in Utilities.R I have

```
# Utilities.R
foo <- function(save_path) {
  print(save_path)
}
```

and in Main.R I have

```
# Main.R
source("Utilities.R")

save_path <- "path/to/folder"

foo(save_path = save_path)
```

However, what I've found is I don't actually need to set `save_path` as a parameter at all. If I set the files as

```
# Utilities.R
foo <- function() {
  print(save_path)
}
```

```
# Main.R
source("Utilities.R")

save_path <- "path/to/folder"

foo()
```

I can achieve the same result since `save_path` exists within the scope of `Main.R`. Is this bad practice? Let's say I have a lot of these global-like variables set/determined in `Main.R` that get used in `foo()`, is it best to pass all of them explicitly?

Comment: yep not a good move, esp. if you ever want to reuse the utilities — best to make everything modular + therefore portable whenever possible (as in the original version) :p

Comment: @lefft thanks, that's what I thought. What if the utilities are pretty self contained to the project/script (I just threw utilities in there as a name, really it's more of a support script I moved code into to clear up the "main" script). Still a bad move?

Comment: i’d say it depends — in general not a best practice but can prob save time in some cases. in general risky to get in the habit imo. but only you know your situation, so maybe it makes sense here!